# Using this.setState in a callback

Tags: javascript, callback, reactjs, this

I have the following code getting a twitter timeline in a react component:

```
  componentWillMount: function() {
    twitter.get('statuses/user_timeline',
    function(error, data) {
      this.setState({tweets: data})
     });
  }
```

But I can't set the `state` there, because `this` isn't set to the component in that callback function.

How can I set the state within that callback?

*n.b. console.log(data) instead of this.setState works fine, which is why I suspect the problem is with the this variable.*

Answer (score 7):

You can set `this` with `.bind` method like this, and call `twitter.get` in [`componentDidMount`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#mounting-componentdidmount) as in this [`example`](http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html)

```
componentDidMount: function() {
   twitter.get('statuses/user_timeline', function(error, data) {
      this.setState({tweets: data})
   }.bind(this)); // set this that refers to you React component
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Never perform ajax call in componentWillMount.

**Do it in componentDidMount**.

Also there is a scope problem, for that use what Alexander suggest (bind). Another possibility is:

```
componentDidMount: function() {
    var self = this;
    twitter.get('statuses/user_timeline', function(error, data) {
        self.setState({tweets: data})
    });
}
```

Also more details here http://facebook.github.io/react/tips/initial-ajax.html (already underlined by klimo in comments)

Comment: Thanks for the mention, Francois. To add briefly to your answer, you can use the ES6 fat arrow to avoid binding or `self = this` altogether: `(error, data) => { ...` (you'll need a transpiler like Babel).

Comment: `componentDidMount` seems to not fire at all for me.
My code:
`getInitialState: function(){
    return({tweets: 'getInitialState'})
  }

  , componentDidMount: function() {
    twitter.get('statuses/user_timeline', function(error, data) {
      this.setState({tweets: 'callback'})
      console.log('callback')
    }.bind(this));
    this.setState({tweets:'componentDidMount'})
    console.log('componentDidMount')
  }`
renders 'getInititialState'

Comment: put the code in your question it's hurting my eyes reading this like that

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways by putting it inside **componentDidMount**, you can solve the issue :

**1. Bind this scope to the function**

.bind(this)

```
twitter.get('statuses/user_timeline', function(error, data) {
   this.setState({tweets: data})
}).bind(this);
```

**2. Use fat arrow**

=>

```
twitter.get('statuses/user_timeline', (error, data) => {
   this.setState({tweets: data})
});
```