# access this in Promise catch block

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, promise, es6-promise

In react native how could I use "this" in Promise catch block?

```
this.guestErrorAlert();
```

in

```
 GuestApi
      .guestLogin()
      .then(function (response) {
        GuestApi.onSuccess(response);
        return response;
      })
      .then(() => this.openLanguageStartupScreen())
      .catch(function (error) {
        GuestApi.onError();
        console.log(error);
        this.guestErrorAlert();
      });
```

Comment: replace `function` with `arrow function` - `() => {}`

Comment: please check last answer :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34109593/using-this-setstate-in-a-callback

Comment: I will try to check if it's work in catch block and report here the result

Comment: catch(function (error) {  }).bind(this) not working

Comment: guestErrorAlert = () => not working

Comment: @amorenew all answers are correct you just implement them wrong

Comment: it's working my fault from using Alert without importing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentionned in the comments, you can either use an arrow-function, or you can define a function and bind it.

Example:

```
let catchCallback = function() {...};
catchCallback = catchCallback.bind(this);

GuestApi.guestLogin()
      .then(...)
      .catch(catchCallback);
```

Hoping this helps!

Comment: not working bind or arrows

Comment: @amorenew Are you doing it properly? I saw your comment above: `catch(function (error) { }).bind(this) not working` but here, you bind this on the result of catch(), not on the callback you pass in catch...
From my experience, bind works perfectly, I use it a lot with React.

Comment: it's working my fault from using Alert without importing it

Comment: Glad you figured it out ;) Have a nice day!

Comment: Nice day to you too-:)

Answer (score 3):

Issue is with scope, use fat arrow to solve the issue.

Replace this code block with :

```
.catch((error) => {
    GuestApi.onError();
    console.log(error);
    this.guestErrorAlert();
});
```